# Custom CSS is not getting applied in .Net Core React App

Tags: css, reactjs, .net-core

I am using Reactstrap and trying to add some custom CSS, but the custom CSS is not getting applied.

Here is the code snippet.

Below is Home.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Button, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import './Home.css'

export class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { showForm: false, btnText: "Add Record", formClass: "formHide" };
        this.addRecord = this.addRecord.bind(this);
    }

    addRecord() {
        if (this.state.btnText === 'Back') {
            this.setState({ btnText: 'Add Record' });
            this.setState({ formClass: "formHide" });
        } else {
            this.setState({ btnText: 'Back' });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <h1 className='centerTitle'>Welcome to Fit Buddy</h1>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={9}></Col>
                    <Col sm={3}>
                        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addRecord}>{this.state.btnText}</Button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Form className={this.state.formClass}>
                    <FormGroup row>
                        <Label for="exampleSelect" sm={3}>Exercise Type</Label>
                        <Col sm={9}>
                            <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect">
                                <option>Push Ups</option>
                                <option>Sit Ups</option>
                            </Input>
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup row>
                        <Label for="exampleReps" sm={3}>No. of Reps</Label>
                        <Col sm={9}>
                            <Input type="text" name="text" id="exampleReps" placeholder="Enter number of Reps" />
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>
                </Form>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Below is Home.css file

```
centerTitle {
    text-align: center !important;
}

formHide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I tried debugging using developer Tools, this is the code, I am able to see. My Style is there and it is applied correctly in HTML as well. Still, my style is not working.

[Code in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ooBR.png)

When trying to provide styling to HTML Tags, it is working. But when giving styles to class, it is not working.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css-file is not targeting anything, since you are missing the dots infront of your classnames.

```
.centerTitle {
   text-align: center !important;
}
.formHide {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Edit: 
Here is a good overview of the different css-selectors:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp